# JPA and Apache Aries: persistence unit unresolved dependency

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, blueprint-osgi, aries

I'm trying to configure a datasource for mysql and a corresp. persistence bundle on top of Apache Aries.
This is the datasource's blueprint file

```
<bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://matteos-mbp:3306/" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="databaseName" value="testDBBlueprint" /> 
    <property name="createDatabaseIfNotExist" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="mysqlXADataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://matteos-mbp:3306/" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="databaseName" value="testDBBlueprint" /> 
    <property name="createDatabaseIfNotExist" value="true" />
</bean>
<service ref="mysqlDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/ddauthdb" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
<service ref="mysqlXADataSource" interface="javax.sql.XADataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/xaddauthdb" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

and these are the persistence.xml and the blueprint.xml files for the entities/persistence bundle (bundle com.mycompany.jpa.auth.entities):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="ddauth">
        <jta-data-source>
osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/xaddauthdb)      
</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>
            osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/ddauthdb)
        </non-jta-data-source>
        <class>com.mycompany.persistence.users.TestUser</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint 
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="userService" class="com.mycompany.persistence.users.UserServiceImpl">
        <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
        <jpa:context property="entityManager" unitname="ddauth"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean
        id="populator"
        class="com.mycompany.persistence.users.Populator"
        init-method="populate"
        activation="eager"    >
        <property
            name="userService"
            ref="userService" />
    </bean>

    <service ref="userService" interface="com.mycompany.users.api.UserService" />
</blueprint>
```

The error I get is

```
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl] : Unable to start blueprint container for bundle com.mycompany.jpa.auth.entities due to unresolved dependencies [(&(&(org.apache.aries.jpa.proxy.factory=true)(osgi.unit.name=ddauth))(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory))]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher] : Sending blueprint container event BlueprintEvent[type=FAILURE, dependencies=[(&(&(org.apache.aries.jpa.proxy.factory=true)(osgi.unit.name=ddauth))(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory))], exception=null] for bundle com.mycompany.jpa.auth.entities
```

My runtime is the following:

```
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|OSGi System Bundle (3.10.2.v20150203-1939)
    1|Active     |    1|aQute.xray.plugin (1.7.0.201403241317)
    2|Active     |    1|com.mycompany.db.mysql.auth (0.0.0.201506180714)
    3|Active     |    1|Oracle Corporation's JDBC Driver for MySQL (5.1.35)
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Commons Collections (3.2.1)
    5|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Blueprint Bundle (1.1.0)
    6|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Blueprint API (1.0.1)
    7|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Blueprint Core (1.4.2)
    8|Active     |    1|Aries JPA Container API (1.0.2)
    9|Active     |    1|Aries JPA Container blueprint integration for Aries blueprint (1.0.4)
   10|Active     |    1|Aries JPA Container (1.0.2)
   11|Active     |    1|Aries JPA Container Managed Contexts (1.0.4)
   12|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Proxy API (1.0.1)
   13|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Proxy Service (1.0.4)
   14|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint (1.0.2)
   15|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Transaction Manager (1.0.0)
   16|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Transaction Manager (1.1.1)
   17|Active     |    1|Apache Aries Util (1.1.0)
   18|Active     |    1|Commons Lang (2.6.0)
   19|Active     |    1|Commons Pool (1.6.0)
   20|Active     |    1|Apache CXF Core (3.1.1)
   21|Active     |    1|Apache CXF Runtime HTTP Transport (3.1.1)
   22|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.8.0)
   23|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.14.0)
   24|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.12.1)
   25|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
   26|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Metatype Service (1.0.10)
   27|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Declarative Services (1.8.2)
   28|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Web Management Console (3.1.8)
   29|Active     |    1|Apache Geronimo JSR-317 JPA 2.0 Spec API (1.1.0)
   30|Active     |    1|geronimo-jta_1.1_spec (1.1.1)
   31|Active     |    1|OpenJPA Aggregate Jar (2.2.2)
   32|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: commons-dbcp (1.4.0.3)
   33|Active     |    1|XmlSchema Core (2.2.1)
   34|Active     |    1|Apache XBean OSGI Bundle Utilities (3.18.0)
   35|Active     |    1|Apache XBean :: Classpath Resource Finder (3.18.0)
   36|Active     |    1|hibernate-jpa-2.1-api (1.0.0.Final)
   37|Active     |    1|ASM all classes with debug info (5.0.3)
   38|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Logging - API (1.8.2)
   39|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Web - Jetty Bundle (4.1.2)
   40|Active     |    1|com.mycompany.jpa.auth.entities (0.0.0.201506180718)
```

Could you help me spotting what is missing here? What is the best approach to debug this kind of situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to a fistful of missing bundles in my runtime. To solve the problem it was enough to look at the *blog sample* project within the Apache Aries Samples and replicate that runtime in my bnd file.

The bundles I added are the following:

- org.apache.aries.transaction.wrappers
- org.apache.aries.jpa.container
- org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context
- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec
- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec
- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jta_1.1_spec
- org.apache.aries.jndi
- org.apache.commons.pool
- org.objectweb.asm.all
- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.serp

Answer (score 2):

The error says that the EntityManagerFactory could not be found in time.

There are two possible reasons. Either the persitence unit was not found at all or there was an error when creating the EntityManagerFactory for it.

If you see no other errors in the log I suspect the persistence unit is not recognized at all. Please check that you have the property Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml in the Manifest of your entities bundle.

One other possible problem might be that you create the DataSource services in the same bundle that needs them. As blueprint only comes up when the EntityManageFactory service is found the DataSources will probably never be initiated. Better put them in another bundle. Even better define the DataSources using pax-jdbc-config.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. The problem was due to some missing bundles in my runtime. I'll try to switch to pax-jdbc-config as you suggested.